# How safe is DirectLine?

Tags: botframework

I have seen a number of posts where developers want to have their clients talk to their Bot directly without using DirectLine, or alternatively emulate DirectLine within their intranet. The most common reason is that their companies are not cloud-ready.

Instead of asking HOW, I want to ask for more information about DirectLine that I can present back to my technology committee. How is direct line secured? How are messages encrypted? Are messages logged anywhere? Are messages retained anywhere at rest?

Can someone point me to a good source of this type of information?

Comment: _How is direct line secured?  How are messages encrypted?_ Directline uses TLS. _Are messages logged anywhere? Are messages retained anywhere at rest?_ Yes, because you can [rejoin a previous conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-reconnect-to-conversation?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

Comment: More information can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#authentication-technologies

Comment: Thank you both. I read about the reconnecting to previous conversation, and it requires conversation Id. That would have user access to the state data for previous conversation which is stored in my Bot storage, not somewhere in the cloud. I could be interpreting it wrong. I am more concerned that when message hits DirectLine API it is stored somewhere in the cloud as well as sent to my Bot.

Comment: The only thing I would add is that the message bodies for the conversation (DirectLine/Webchat) are only cached for 24 hours before being destroyed.  As such, you won't be able to reconnect to an old conversation and get content; but the conversation ID will still be durable.

Note also that the conversation id's live for only 28 days after the last message in the conversation and then those are deleted as well.